# Google Photos upload via API automatically deleting certain videos after processing

Tags: video, file-upload, google-api, google-photos, google-photos-api

I wrote a basic tool to upload media to Google Photos via the official API: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media

Everything in the described flow works, I'm able to upload media and create the media item in Google Photos.

I receive a photoURL containing the processing video. However, a short while after the video processes the URL starts returning a 404 and the upload is gone from the Photos Library.

This doesn't happen with all videos - An arbitrary MP4 and MOV tested work just fine, but various media from a GoPro camera (MP4 in 4K) fails consistently.

Answer (score 1):

> *"but various media from a GoPro camera (MP4 in 4K) fails consistently."*

Unconfirmed but most likely it's failing because Go-Pro uses **H.265** codec (aka HEVC) for 4K recordings but Google Photos supports/expects 4K to be in **H.264** codec.

- Use a tool like [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download) to check if the failing video is really H265/HEVC.
- Using your video editor (or a free tool like FFmpeg) to extract a few seconds and re-encode to H.264 (in an MP4 container). Test uploading this new encoding.